# How to import data from json objects using ajax js?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How to get variable which allow to get 'prod_id' from all objects 0,1,2?. I tried several ways, but i can get only object in console. I want to use ${}, don't know how.

```js
let url = "http://localhost:3000";

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url + `/0/0/0/`,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    },
});
```

```js
{
  "0": {
    "prod_id": "1",
    "prod_added": "2015-08-25 15:15:22",
    "prod_producer": "7",
    "prod_amount": "8.0000",
    },

  "1": {
    "prod_id": "2",
    "prod_added": "2015-08-25 15:15:22",
    "prod_producer": "7",
    "prod_amount": "8.0000",
  },
  "2": {
    "prod_id": "3",
    "prod_added": "2015-08-25 15:15:22",
    "prod_producer": "8",
    "prod_amount": "39996.0000",
  }
}
```

Comment: still not working could you write all code please?

Comment: `const productIds = Object.values(data).map(({ prod_id }) => prod_id)`. That will give you an array of the `prod_id` values